# Loop array within another array on React Native

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, react-native, push

I am trying do loop over a prop and push the parent and child to a variable. I seem to be able to get the looping and pushing working correctly, but its pushing all the children under each parent

```
var options = [];
    var option = [];
    Object.keys(this.props.data.options).forEach((key, index) => {
      options.push(
        <AddToCartRow key={index} option={key} options={option} cartKey={this.props.cartKey} />,
        Object.values(this.props.data.options[key]).forEach((value, index) => {
          option.push(value)
        })
      )
    })
```

Below is what is currently happening

[image]

The expected result should be

**size**
 - 0[price: 3.95, title: Small]
- 1 [price: 4.95, title: Large]

**blend**
 - 0[price: 0, title: Regular]
- 1 [price: 0, title: Decaf]

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have problem with pushing element into array. I have managed by doing  as below

```
for (let parentData of mainObj) {
    let tempArray = []; // need to declare here
    for (let childData of parentData.someField) {
        tempArray.push({
            ...
        });
    }
    finalArray.push(tempArray);
}
```

You need to push your child loop data into temporary array and then to main resultant array which is `options` in your case .

Comment: isnt this what I am doing already I have the child loop within the primary loop

Comment: yes it is similar,the only difference is `var option = [];` declared above, I have used in before child loop. So each time it will be created as new array and append to primary loop